# How to let floating div span total width, if second div is empty?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a template which should accommodate two layouts:
I have a container with div A (left) and div B (right). A has always content. If B has content, it's width should be 30%, A gets the rest. Both colums should have 100% heigth, no floating around the shorter element.
If B is empty, it should not show at all and A should take up 100% width.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <placeholder 1 />
    <placeholder 2 />
  </div>
  <div class="right"><!-- can be empty -->
    <placeholder 3 />
    <placeholder 4 />  
  </div>
</div>
```

I would love to do this with just css. Is it possible?
Or am I going to need to use javascript? IE6 is not an issue…

Comment: When you say `.right` can be "empty", do you mean "completely empty" as in `<div class="right"></div>`?

Comment: yes, placeholders 3 and 4 will be completely gone.

Comment: Is completely removing `<div class="right"></div>` instead of just everything inside it an option? Would it be acceptable to use [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) to "fake" having equal height columns? I have a pure CSS solution, but making it work in IE7 is difficult without resorting to JavaScript.

Comment: Removing div.right would require some scripting, but I im unsure about the condition for the removing, so no.  
Faux columns are ok.  
Please share your solution, even if it doesn't work for IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/3mDnr/

That works in IE8+ and all modern browsers.

It *almost* works in IE7 - the only problem is that the "empty right `div`" refuses to hide. There just isn't a pure CSS way to fix that, so I've included a snippet of jQuery-powered JavaScript to do it:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.right:empty').hide();
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can use the [faux columns technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)  to fake equal height columns.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">..</div>
    <div class="left">
        ..
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden
}
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background: cyan
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default if `B` is without content, the div will be 100% of nothing, which makes it 0%; If there is content there, it will expand to the size of the content. But if you place a max width of 30%, you will have it go away with no content and have it max at 30%.

```
B.div {
    max-width:30%;
}
```

Comment: thx phil. but either I'm not getting it or I didn't make myself quite clear. I'll try again.
I tried to make columns by floating A:
`.left{float:left;}`
this doesn't work without also stating a width. which I dont know, it depending on B being empty or not.
If I put B before A in the markup:
`<div class="container">
      <div class="right">B</div>
      <div class="left">A</div>
</div>`
and float B instead of A, also giving B a width:
`.right{float:right;width: 100px;}` they behave nicely as far as emptying and filling B, except their resistance towards my clearing: A keeps floating around B.

Answer (score 1):

I tried accomplishing what I thought you meant with CSS only, but wasn't able to accomplish it. To achieve what I thought you needed, I had to add a little javascript.

Edit:
Just remove the content from 'div B' and re-run the fiddle to see how it handles no content.

http://jsfiddle.net/QrNu7/21/

Comment: yes, you got the idea :)
I'm still looking for a css only solution. but your script would definitely do the trick, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your floats - but this should be ok for handling the width issue you describe.  Am I missing something?

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        <placeholder 1 />
        <placeholder 2 />
      </div>
      <div class="right"><!-- can be empty -->
        <placeholder 3 />
        <placeholder 4 />  
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

in your stylesheet

```
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: seems I had some troubles expressing myself. thanx anyways.